# Multi Select Custom Validation Rule

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-multiselect

I'm trying to create a custom validation rule to ensure that at least one selection is made within a select with the multiple attribute. I have a jsfiddle showing what I have at this point but I can't get the validation rule to fire. I have included the jQuery script that is translating the select just in case this might be casing my issue. My code is in the document ready section at the bottom of the JavaScript window. The jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/7bkz58cy/25/

```
$.validator.addMethod('multiSelectRequired', function (value, element) {
    return element.length > 0;
}, 'One selection required.');

$('#activity-dialog-form').validate({
    rules: {
        FacilityList: { multiSelectRequired: true }
    }
});
```

I can't figure out why the validation isn't firing. Can someone please point out what I'm missing.

Comment: It's not a standard `select` with a `multiple` attribute.  You're also using the jQuery UI Multi-select widget.  It's important to mention this.  Thanks.

Comment: Another bit of important information is that there is also a reference to http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.1/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js after the reference to jquery.validate.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't figure out why the validation isn't firing.

One of the reasons your validation is not working is because you are calling the `.validate()` method twice on the same form.  You can only call the `.validate()` method once, as all subsequent calls are completely ignored.  Since your rules are declared in the second instance, they are ignored.

The `.validate()` method would only ever be called ***once***, on DOM ready, to initialize the plugin on your form, and this same instance contains any rules, options, callbacks, etc.

---

In this most basic example, I simply put the `required` rule (`required="required"`) on a `select` element, with a `multiple="multiple"` attribute, and the validation is working without custom rules/methods:  https://jsfiddle.net/csj35fj8/

Shown within your code:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lzmh0qtg/2/

```
$('#activity-dialog-form').validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
        FacilityList: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        FacilityList: {
            required: 'One selection required.'
        }
    }
});
```

Since you're using the `.multiselect()` jQuery UI widget to dynamically change the appearance of the select field, you can no longer validate it as the original `select` element is now hidden.

You will need to set the `ignore` option to `[]` in order to ignore "nothing" so that the hidden `select` is validated.

---

In order to automatically hide the validation error message when the user makes a selection, use a `change` handler to trigger the `.valid()` method on this element.

```
$('.multiselect').on('change', function() {
    $(this).valid(); 
});
```

This workaround is needed since the jQuery Validate plugin, by default, is only looking at events on the *original* `select` element, which is now hidden.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lzmh0qtg/3/**

Comment: I have put this exact code in my application but the validation isn't happening. I thought maybe one of the other controls might be causing an issue so I created a fork from your working DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/8c2tfv5n/1/  and placed all my HTML which is showing the validation message. The valid call in the code is returning true if ($('#activity-dialog-form').valid()) { Is there a way for me to see if the rule is applied? I'm not sure where else to look. Any suggestions?

Comment: @KrisHahn, I am not sure what you're asking me... your forked jsFiddle is working, so how can I locate a problem that you're not showing me?  You can attach `.valid()` to the one field, instead of the form, and it too will return a boolean value representing the validity of the field.  However, if `.valid()` is returning `true` when it's attached to the `form`, then all fields already passed validation.  You can put `debug: true` within `.validate()` and look at the console log.

Comment: You'll just have to more carefully compare the jsFiddle line-by-line to your application.  Also making sure you've included all relevant files and not renamed any elements.

Comment: Thanks for the debug insight.

Comment: @KrisHahn, did the `debug` option give you any console messages?

Comment: nothing is showing in the console. I tried Firefox and Chrome nothing showing in either. When I place a break point on the $(this).valid() in the change event for the select it is showing valid is true when selecting and deselecting an item.

Comment: no the debug didn't show anything in the console and I tried using Firefox and Chrome. After everything is loaded up and I looked at the context of the control I drilled down enough to see that it had required as **false**. So I removed the ui-Multiselect widget functionality and it is working like expected. So I have to figure out what the widget is doing to keep if from validating. What I don't get it why it is working in the jsfiddle and not in my applications. I still haven't found that line which is different. Still looking....

Comment: I determined that the issue is my reference to jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js Taking your working model and adding that reference causes the behavior I'm seeing in my application. See jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jo0v1pew/1/ Can these two not work together?

Comment: @KrisHahn, when using `unobtrusive` you cannot use `.validate()`, because `unobtrusive` already calls it once.  IMO, when you need to do this much customization, remove `unobtrusive` entirely.  Otherwise, you might have some luck using [the `.setDefaults()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/).

Answer (score 0):

In your custom validate method you should check `value` instead of `element`.

The `value` can be either `null` (if empty) or `array`. So that you can just check whether it's not `null`:

```
$.validator.addMethod('multiSelectRequired', function (value, element) {
    return value !== null;
}, 'One selection required.');
```

Or if you require more than one selection, check also length of the `value` array:

```
$.validator.addMethod('multiSelectRequired', function (value, element) {
    // minimum two options selected:
    return value !== null && value.length > 1;
}, 'Two selections required.');
```

Next thing is that the `<select>` element is initialy hidden (invisible to the user) and for that reason it's skipped in validation process (it's set that by default). To make hidden fields being also validated, add `ignore` option:

```
$('#activity-dialog-form').validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
        FacilityList: { multiSelectRequired: true }
    }
});
```

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzmh0qtg/)

---

Another thing is that you have positioning issues.

The ultimate way would be to put the form inside dialog, instead of appending the dialog to the form here:

```
open: function (type, data) {
   $(this).parent().appendTo($('#activity-dialog-form'));
   // ...
```

If you need to append it to the form for some reason, you should disable dialog overlay, because it will be above of the dialog (as your form has lower z-index than overlay).

To disable overlay, change `modal` option to `false` (or delete it as it's set to `false` by default):

```
$('#activity-event-dialog').show().dialog({
    //modal: false,
```

Comment: Good work.  Perhaps mention that you removed the OP's duplicate instance of `.validate()`.  Also, the `.validate()` method does not need to be inside the `open` callback.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lzmh0qtg/1/

Comment: Finally, there is no need for a custom method in the first place.  The OP's specification to ensure at least one is selected is already properly satisfied by simply using the `required` rule.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lzmh0qtg/2/